# Not able to find azure media service key

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have created a azure media service in azure portal,

in code i have to fill

```
 <appSettings>
<add key="MediaServicesAccountName" value="" />
<add key="MediaServicesAccountKey" value="" />
```

but i couldnot find the keys anywhere.

what i can see when i select the media service is
[image]

i  have referred a  [link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/a-look-into-windows-azure-media-services/) but the ui seems to be entirely diffrent.

please help me where i can find the key and name?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [`blog post`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-media-service-aad-auth-and-acs-deprecation/?cdn=disable) by Azure Media Service team, use of account name/key to connect to and manage your Media Service account is deprecated. It is recommended that you use Azure AD based authentication. More details about this can be found on the same blog post as well as in the `API Access` section in Azure Portal.

[image]

Comment: Gaurav is correct. We have moved away from the older ACS keys to support Azure Active Directoy. Look under the API Access blade as noted, and follow the AAD auth guides in our docs.

If you picked up that code from a public repo or samples, please let us know so that we can contact the owner of that sample to update it.

Comment: Also - I recommend using Service Principals and not user auth in most all cases. Unless you are building a desktop management app for yourself.

Comment: did anyone find any example for uploading something using AAD authentication?
i couldnt find any. a link myt be very help full, thanks......

Comment: You need to get the writable SAS URL to the Asset using Locators API in Media Services, and then upload via block blob apis in Azure Storage SDK. 
REST API sample article is here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-upload-files

Comment: what i need to if its simple console app?

Comment: BTW - we are working on a new REST API (v3) that will support ingest from arbitrary Storage location, and ingest from http URL.  Let us know if you have other needs for simplifying ingest

Comment: For simple console app, you can just get the SAS URL as noted in that article, and use AZCopy to upload to it

Comment: The SAS URL that you get for a writable Asset Locator is just a SAS URL to a container in Blob storage - so you can use it to upload with AZCopy as noted here. Or use the Storage SDK .NET SDK or other SDK to do it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#upload-blobs-to-blob-storage

Comment: Also, don't forget Azure Media Services Explorer - for a simple client tool on Windows.

Comment: I also have samples using Azure Functions and Logic Apps up here to automate the ingest.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-dotnet-functions-integration/tree/master/100-basic-encoding

Comment: i have seen som code using previous way in link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1102643/Working-With-Azure-Media-Service-Account 

and the link gaurav provide shows the diffrence. but at the end, both gives an object of CloudMediaContext ..
so can i use this object to upload as in the first link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163744/discussion-between-hilda-sonica-vish-and-johndeu).

Comment: It's tough for us to scan the web and clean up sample projects on "codeproject" and github that we don't own to correct the usage for AAD authentication. It would be great to "comment" on the articles you come across using the old ACS method. That can really help the community.